# Подскажите ошибку в коде мульти язычного сайта php

Tags: php

Причина язык не устанавливается на пользовательский

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * Date: 18.05.2018
 * Time: 1:30PM
 */

preg_match_all('/([a-z]{1,8}(?:-[a-z]{1,8})?)(?:;q=([0-9.]+))?/', 
strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]), $matches);
$lang = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]); 
foreach ($lang as $n => $v)
$lang[$n] = $v ? $v : 1;
arsort($lang);
$default_lang = key($lang);
echo $default_lang;
if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}else{
$lang = 'ru-RU';
}
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
setcookie ("lang", $lang, time() + 3600*24, "/");
}
$listDataIni = parse_ini_file("inc/lang/".$lang.".ini");
?>
```